# How can I get the WordPress language_attributes function to return valid XHTML 1.1?

Tags: php, wordpress, w3c-validation, xml-attribute, xhtml-1.1

I have a WordPress template that contains the following element:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" <?php language_attributes('xhtml'); ?>>
```

This returns:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" dir="ltr" lang="en-US" xml:lang="en-US">
```

Unfortunately the "lang" attribute is invalid XHTML 1.1 - and the client would like this level of validation.

WordPress' general-template.php file contains the following code:

```
if ( get_option('html_type') == 'text/html' || $doctype == 'html' )
    $attributes[] = "lang=\"$lang\"";
```

`$doctype` is the parameter passed to it (in this case 'xhtml'). Should `get_option` be returning a value other than 'text/html'? If so, what should I be setting in WordPress to achieve this - if anything?

I've also tried using preg_replace to take out the "lang" attribute, but this didn't seem to be able to match the text. If I enter the text manually, it matches! Possibly an encoding issue with the string being returned by language_attributes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this. There's a "language_attributes" filter, so I wrote a [plugin](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API) that hooks into that and does a simple preg_replace. The replace worked when performed here, and it's a pretty neat way to handle it.

**EDIT**

As requested, here's the code I used:

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: Create Valid XHTML 1.1
Plugin URI: http://www.mycompany.com/create_valid_xhtml_1_1
Description: Removes deprecated "lang" attribute from (X)HTML header.
Author: dommer
Version: 1.0.0
Author URI: http://www.mycompany.com
*/

function create_valid_xhtml_1_1($language_attributes) 
{
    return preg_replace('/ lang=\"[a-z]+\-[A-Z]+\"/', '', $language_attributes);
}

add_filter('language_attributes', 'create_valid_xhtml_1_1');
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

If this is just a theme on your own site, you could edit header.php and change the

`<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" <?php language_attributes('xhtml'); ?>>`

line to be hardcoded, improves performance too :-)

Comment: That's an option. But I'm not sure to what other uses the client may put the template, so, if I can, I'd like to retain that functionality.