# Wordpress, Setting language for each post?

Tags: wordpress, plugins

I have a blog and I want to write some posts in spanish and some other in english (no post will be in both languages).

So, I want to be able change the value returned by **language_attributes()** function for certain posts. I've seen that **language_attributes()** uses **get_bloginfo('language')**. So I guess in wordpress, language is designed to be at 'the whole site' level rather than at 'post' or 'page' level.

I think I only have two solutions: to write a plugin in  which I can define the language for each post (which would have to use a filter like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1805718/how-can-i-get-the-wordpress-language-attributes-function-to-return-valid-xhtml-1). Or to use a multi-language plugin, which is a too sophisticated solution for my simple problem.

Any other ideas? Any other plugin o simple solution?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are plug-ins already available for setting up a multilingual WordPress blog. You might want to have a look into this topic: http://codex.wordpress.org/Multilingual_WordPress. So, you could use an existing plug-in.

Comment: I chose qTranslate, although what I wanted was something simpler. But qTranslate is cool